# How do I collapse (element-wise for maximum, minimum, or mean) a multi-dimensional numpy array for a subset of indices along a specific axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean, elementwise-operations

I currently have a numpy array of the shape (71, 136, 136, 130); the exact dimensions vary. This is volume data (e.g., temperature) in the form [Time, Z, Y, X]. I am allowing the user to specify the time range to collapse the  Z, Y, X volume element-wise for the maximum, minimum, or mean.

I was able to successfully collapse the array element-wise for maximum and minimum in a Time index range of 20-70 (example indices) by using a while loop taking one Time slice at a time. However, this loop approach won't work when calculating the mean.

I should probably be able to perform these operations (maximum, minimum, or mean) without a loop structure. The np.maximum() and np.minimum() functions require two arrays, so I can't seem to arrange the code like `np.maximum(array[20:70,:,:,:])` which I'd want Python/numpy to infer I only want the indices 20-70 used for the returned maximum array. The np.mean() function seems to operate a little differently, but in principle I'd like it to work the same way; averaging the data element-wise over only the time indices specified. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Based on comments here is some simplified example code. Note that when I get the data it is in the form of the full_array; I don't actually manually construct it.

```py
import numpy as np  
    
time0_xy_data = np.array([[22, 80, 17, 98, 42, 46], [36, 11, 95, 23, 77, 12]])  
time1_xy_data = np.array([[12, 97, 85, 68, 44, 43], [15, 84, 91, 33, 13, 56]])  
time2_xy_data = np.array([[45, 26, 37, 93,  2, 28], [73, 78, 72, 48, 62, 62]])  
time3_xy_data = np.array([[42, 67, 59, 60, 55, 67], [21, 32, 88, 87, 23, 15]])
    
full_array = np.array([time0_xy_data, time1_xy_data, time2_xy_data, time3_xy_data])  

# Get the element-wise maximum of [0:1,:,:,:]  
maximum_slice = np.maximum(full_array[0:1 :, :])  
    
print(maximum_slice)  

# What I expect to get back:  
maximum_slice = np.array([[22, 97, 85, 98, 44, 46], [36, 84, 95, 33, 77, 56]])
```

Comment: What do you mean "returned maximum array"? Can you please post some example data (2 dimensions are probably sufficient) and your expected output?

Comment: The issue with np.max,() and np.min(), is the result is a single scalar value. I need to retain the z, y, x structure. If you use np.maximum() or np.minimum() you get a multidimensional result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `axis` parameter of `np.max`, `np.min`, and `np.mean`:

```
> np.max(full_data[0:2], axis=0)
array([[22, 97, 85, 98, 44, 46],
       [36, 84, 95, 33, 77, 56]])

> np.mean(full_data[1:3], axis=0)
array([[28.5, 61.5, 61. , 80.5, 23. , 35.5],
       [44. , 81. , 81.5, 40.5, 37.5, 59. ]])

> np.min(full_data[2:], axis=0)
array([[42, 26, 37, 60,  2, 28],
       [21, 32, 72, 48, 23, 15]])
```

> axis : None or int or tuple of ints, optional
> Axis or axes along which to operate.  By default, flattened input is
> used.

Comment: Excellent! I think that is exactly what I was looking for. The axis parameter makes it work the way I was hoping.